# Grouped, binned, cumulative sum in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, numpy, countif, pandas-groupby

I'm making the transition from excel Countifs/Sum to Pandas. In Pandas then I want to do an grouped, binned, cumulative sum on some input data that I then want write as an output table to a csv.

My input table is a time stamped list of items occurring per project like:

```
import pandas as pd

df_in = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date' :[pd.Timestamp('20130101'),pd.Timestamp('20140101'),pd.Timestamp('20150101'),pd.Timestamp('20160101'),pd.Timestamp('20160101'),pd.Timestamp('20160101')],
'Type' : ['item1','item2','item2','item1','item1','item1'],
'Proj' : ['PJ1','PJ1','PJ1','PJ1','PJ2','PJ2']})

#giving    
Proj    Date     Type
PJ1 2013-01-01  item1
PJ1 2014-01-01  item2
PJ1 2015-01-01  item2
PJ1 2016-01-01  item1
PJ2 2016-01-01  item1
PJ2 2016-01-01  item1
```

And I want to do a cumulative sum of each item type per project over a series of user defined time windows (In the end I want the cumulative number of items achieved per project over a timeset - month,quarter,year etc). My output (binned to the end date) should look like

```js
Proj       Date_        item1 item2
PJ1     2014-01-01      1.0   1.0
PJ1     2016-01-01      2.0   2.0
PJ2     2014-01-01      0.0   0.0
PJ2     2016-01-01      2.0   0.0
```

This code works but seems clumsy and requires looping. Is there a better way of achieving the output? Maybe something vectorised? Further, I always want to retain the output bins, even if there is null data in them - they are needed later for consistent plotting.

```js
#prepare output table
df_out = pd.DataFrame({
'Date_' : [],
'Proj' : [],
'item1' : [],
'item2' : []})

#my time bins
bins = [pd.Timestamp('20121229'),pd.Timestamp('20140101'),pd.Timestamp('20160101')]

#group and bin data in a dataframe
groups = df_in.groupby(['Proj',pd.cut(df_in.Date, bins),'Type'])
allData = groups.count().unstack()

 #list of projects in data
 proj_list = list(set(df_in['Proj'])) 

 #build output table by looping per project
 for p in proj_list:
   #cumulative sum of items achieved per project per bin
   ProjData = allData.loc[p].fillna(0).cumsum()

   #output should appear binned to the end date 
   ProjData=ProjData['Date'][:]
   ProjData['Date_']=pd.IntervalIndex(ProjData.index.get_level_values('Date')).right
   #include row wise project reference
   ProjData['Proj']=p
   #collapse the multi-dimensional dataframe for outputting
   ProjData.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
   ProjData.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

   #build output table for export
   df_out = df_out.append(ProjData[['Date_','Proj','item1','item2']])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import itertools

>>> index = list(itertools.product(df['Date'].unique(), df['Proj'].unique()))
>>> df.sort_values(['Proj', 'Date'], inplace=True)
>>> df['CumCount'] = df.groupby(['Proj', 'Type']).cumcount() + 1
>>> df.drop_duplicates(['Date', 'Type', 'Proj'], keep='last', inplace=True)
>>> df = df.pivot_table(values='CumCount', index=['Date', 'Proj'], columns='Type')
>>> df.reindex(index).unstack('Proj').fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0).stack()

Type                item1   item2
Date        Proj        
2013-01-01  PJ1     1.0     0.0
            PJ2     0.0     0.0
2014-01-01  PJ1     1.0     1.0
            PJ2     0.0     0.0
2015-01-01  PJ1     1.0     2.0
            PJ2     0.0     0.0
2016-01-01  PJ1     2.0     2.0
            PJ2     2.0     0.0
```